# Location on iPhone, subThoroughfare is null

Tags: iphone, localization, mkreversegeocoder

I'm developing an app that saves the street of the user's current location. I already have the location, and I´m using geocoder to get the street and the number:

```
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
{
    // with the placemark you can now retrieve the city name
    [self setCity:placemark.subLocality];
    [self setStreet:placemark.thoroughfare];
    [self setNumber:placemark.subThoroughfare];

}
```

Everything goes all right, but I`m in Argentina, and the placemark's subthoroughfare field is always null.

I found something related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335094/mapkit-stopped-sending-subthoroughfare-when-the-coordinates-dont-correspond-to ,  but i always get null even in exact positions (in Argentina). In android, i'm able to get streets numbers without any problem.

Any advice will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I solved the issue using the google apis to reatrive the location.